# Update the quantity of cart using PHP & SQL

Tags: php

I've this problem in which I can't update the cart for some reason. I've looked for many solutions to see if they can solve my problem but no luck. I've 2 files one called `cart.php` which contains the form and a `updatebasket.php` file which contains query.

**Cart file**

```
<?php
     $count = 0;
     while ($count < $numrow)
     {
     $row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
     extract($row);
     echo"<div>";
     echo"<div class='recommended_games'>";
     echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
     echo "</div>";


     echo '<div class="price_tag">';
     echo '<div class="price_tag">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
     echo'</div>';

     echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="POST" name="updateform">';
     echo '<input type="text" value="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" />';
     echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name='.$gameID.' id="gameid" />';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';                                            

     echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
     echo"</div>";
     $count = $count + 1;        
     }        
  ?>
```

**updatebasket file**

```
    <?php
session_start();
require "dbconnect.php";

$memberID = $_SESSION['id']; 

$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$gameID = $_POST['gameid'];
mysqli_autocommit($con,FALSE);
$connect->query($query);


$query = "UPDATE basket SET quantity = ".$quantity." WHERE gameid = ".$gameID." AND id = ".$memberID."";

$results = $connect->query($query);


mysqli_commit($con);
header('Location: cart.php');
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether $quantity and $gameID get values??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `cart.php` to this:

```
<?php
     $count = 0;
     while ($count < $numrow)
     {
     $row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
     extract($row);
     echo"<div>";
     echo"<div class='recommended_games'>";
     echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
     echo "</div>";


     echo '<div class="price_tag">';
     echo '<div class="price_tag">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
     echo'</div>';

     echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="POST" name="updateform">';
     echo '<input type="text" value="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" />';
     echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
     echo '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
     echo '</form>';
     echo '</div>';                                            

     echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
     echo"</div>";
     $count = $count + 1;        
     }        
  ?>
```

The big change is this:

BEFORE:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name='.$gameID.' id="gameid" />';
```

AFTER:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
```

php uses the name attribute as the key for post and get, not id.

id is used by javascript, jquery (also javascript), css, and probably a few other things.

But in forms, name is the one you want for the post and get key.

Comment: thank you very much for your help as you can see im quite new to php, but will defintealy learn from this mistake. i really appreciate the help since i have been trying to get this to work for a long time but just couldnt get my head round why